Story about a teleporter operator becoming a messianic savior
This is a story I read in my local library in 2021. Books seems to went to the back storage so I can't look at there anymore. I read it in French (could easlily have been a translation) and in paperback (so it's at least a few years older even for the last one).
This was a trilogy, of what I would call Epic Science Fiction. While the setting is clearly in SF, a lot of the codes and storyline are from Epic Fantasy (Magic, Religion, Shamanism). While there are fantastic animals, and 'advanced' humans, I don't seem to remember 'pure' Aliens/Elves.
In some way, it feels very much like Hyperion Cantos.
First book
The first book starts with the quest of a woman, trying to get in contact with family member (or familiy friend), she came to the planet the MC is working, as a teleporter operator to be sent to her destination planet.
Once sent away, the bad guys arrive and interrogate the teleporter operator, before pushing into a river where man-eating shark/crocodile beast whould surely dispatch of him.
Fortunatly those creature are in fact intelligent, and recognise the MC as a savior and instead of killing him, save him and give him/active some powers.
From then, he will try to save the woman and help her on her quest, while trying to avoid the bad guys.

 At some point, the MC find he can magically teleport.

Second book
The second book follow the quests of multiple groups trying to meet the original MC and woman

 to earth (I don't remember if the MC is there at the start, or if we follow their travel too), where they are now a couple.

At some point, one group arrive at some religious (jews or protestant) enclave planet, and the next step of travel would require the characters to go inside the ovisac/womb of space faring birds, right after they laid egg/baby.
There is also one character of that specific religion that always state their feelings with 'My heart wants XXX , but my brain wants YYY'.
At the end

 A character betrays everyone (not really a surprise, we know from the start he his the traitor, even if we can hope a change of mind) and lead the bad guys to the MC & Family, ending with the MC's wife and daughter being captured.

Third book

 We follow the stories of multiple 'chosen one' with the knowledge that they must regroup with the MC to fight what I remember being a living black hole, that destroy the universe simply by growing.

One of those new characters is girl whose job is to 'maintain'/tend snake-like infested gigantic ivy stalk that hold a strata of rocks, protecting the planet from an otherwise deadly sun.

Bits of this remind me of The Journeys of McGill Feighan, but only broad strokes, I think.
